# how to filter a django query set by a foreign key in restful framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

i met a problem when using django + restful framework.

here is my intention:

there are many chapters, each chapter has many words, each word has many expand explanations, these explanations are offered by users, so some of them are invaild, in the backend i can set these expands' field **is_alive** to **False**.

in the **views.py**, currently i send all these data to frontend, i tried many ways to filter these invaild data out, but failed.

here are codes:

**models.py**

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    chap = models.IntegerField('chaptername')

class Word(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey('Chapter', related_name='voca')
    word = models.CharField('name', max_length=255)

class Expand(models.Model):
    belong = models.ForeignKey('Word', related_name='expand')
    explansion = models.TextField('description')
    is_alive = models.BooleanField('status', default=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ExpandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Expand
        fields = ('explansion', )

class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    expand = ExpandSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
         model = Word
         fields = ('id', 'word', 'expand')

class ChapterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    voca = WordSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = ('id', 'chap', 'voca')
```

**views.py**

```
def getChapter(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':

        chapter = Chapter.objects.get(pk=1)
        serializer_c = ChapterSerializer(chapter)
        return JsonResponse(serializer_c.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple way use [`serializers.SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    expand = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
         model = Word
         fields = ('id', 'word', 'expand')

    def get_expand(self, obj):
        qs = obj.expand.filter(is_alive=True)
        serializer = ExpandSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

Comment: i want to know where can i find the related docs. i've checkd relevant official docs, but never found this.

Comment: in the answer `use serializers.SerializerMethodField` it is link try it